# Adjusting pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am having trouble controlling the axes in pgfplots. I have defined an evironment for graphs

```
\newenvironment{graph}[3][]{\begin{figure}[htp]
\def\tempa{#1} %Saves caption since \end cannot take arguments
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1] 
\draw node at (7,0) { \Large     $ #2 $ }; %variable on x-axis
\draw node at (0,6.1) { \Large $ #3 $}; %variable on y-axis
\begin{axis}[
      axis lines=left,
      axis equal,
      %ticks=none,
      %xlabel=$x$,
      %ylabel=$y$,
      %width=8cm,
      %height=8cm,
      domain=0:10.5,
      restrict y to domain=0:10.5
      samples=1000
  ]


}
{
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
\ifdefempty{\tempa}{}{\caption{\tempa}} %Creates caption if argument is present.
\end{figure}

}
```

As you can see, I have been experimenting a bit with the axes. My problem is, that they are not of equal length. I would like them to have the same fixed domain 0:10.5, and be of the same exact length (cm). Usually the y-axis is shorter than the x-axis.
In line 5 and 6 I define the names of the axes. As you can see the variables are placed at 6.1 instead of something like 10.5 which I defined the dimension of the axis to be. I would like be able to use the the coordinates of the axis when i use the draw command.

[image: 1]

If I set the position to 10, the nodes are totally misplaced.

```
\draw node at (10,0) { \Large    $ #2 $ }; %variable on x-axis
```

[image: 2]

The last problem is that the draw function does not work within the environment

```
\begin{graph}{x}{y}
\draw[dotted] (0,0) -- (2,2);
\end{graph}
```

This gives me nothing:

[image: 3]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `tikzpicture` coordinate system is not the same as the `axis` coordinate system. You can place `node`s inside the `axis`, read in the manual about the `axis cs` coordinate system. Why not use `xlabel`/`ylabel` though? The `axis equal` option may also be of interest.

Comment: Is it possible to force the tikz and axis coordinate systems to use the same coordinates? 
I dont like how xlabel and ylabel places the variables.

Comment: As I said, if you place your nodes *inside* the `axis` you can use the coordinate system of the axis, e.g. `\node at (axis cs:0,10.5) {$y$};`. But you can of course modify the location of `xlabel`/`ylabel`, see chapter 4.9.3 *Labels* in the manual. (I may write an answer later, but if anyone else wants to, please don't hesitate.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a suggestion. I used `unit vector ratio=1 1 1` instead of `axis equal` because `axis equal` seems to extend the x-axis a bit, no idea why. The axis labels are placed using `xlabel`/`ylabel`, and the position modified by changing the `every axis x label` style, similar for `y`. Note that the coordinates are relative to the axis, so for example `(0,1)` is at the top of the y-axis.

(I removed the `\caption` stuff because I don't know where `\ifdefempty` comes from, so that part wouldn't work.)

If you want to use `\draw` and similar in the `graph` environment, use the `axis cs` coordinate system, as you can see in the examples below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\newenvironment{graph}[3][]{\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
      axis lines=middle,
      unit vector ratio=1 1 1,
      every axis x label/.style={at={(1,0)},font=\Large,right},
      every axis y label/.style={at={(0,1)},font=\Large,above},
      xlabel=#2,
      ylabel=#3,
      domain=0:10.5,
      xmin=0,xmax=10.5,
      ymin=0,ymax=10.5,
      samples=100,
      no marks
  ]
}
{
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
} 
\begin{document}
\begin{graph}{$x$}{$y$}
\addplot {x};
\addplot {x+1};
\addplot {x-1};
\draw [dotted] (axis cs:0,10.5) -- (axis cs:10.5,10.5) -- (axis cs:10.5,0);
\end{graph}

\begin{graph}{$X$}{$Y$}
\addplot {8*sin(deg(x))*sin(deg(x))};
\draw [thick,latex-latex] (axis cs:1.57,8) to[out=40,in=140] node[above]{random} (axis cs:3.14+1.57,8);
\end{graph}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. That completely answered my question. 
Unfortunately I have stumbled upon a new problem:
How can I write something underneath the x-axis?

Comment: @user1067911 `\node [below=1cm] at (rel axis cs:0.5,0) {something};` should work I suppose.

Comment: It doesnt seem to work. No text is created.

Comment: @user1067911 Ah, sorry, my mistake. By default everything outside axis boundaries is clipped, add `clip mode=individual` to the `axis` options.